# How to move from Jenkins as service to Jenkins as application?

Tags: jenkins, service, windows-server-2012-r2

Running Jenkins 2.46.3 as a Windows service (Windows Server 2012 R2) does not allow me to interact with desktop applications. I've tried to fix this but it did not work for me (by changing registry settings), so I would like to run Jenkins as an application.

The problem is that when I run command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar jenkins.war` Jenkins is extracted to `C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins` folder and I have to setup it from the begining.

I don't want to setup it from the begining, I would like to run current installation as an application from the same folder it has been installed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell where your Jenkins home directory is located. You can see your current Jenkins home directory in `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System` -> `Home directory`. (e.g `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`)

Then create a new environment variable called `JENKINS_HOME` to your Jenkins home directory (e.g `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`).

Stop your Jenkins instance, **close your current command interpreter and start a new one**, and launch Jenkins with your command (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar jenkins.war`).

Comment: Maybe to first set `JENKINS_HOME` env/sys variable, then start jenkins, check in `jenkinsURL/systemInfo` variables `HOME` and `JENKINS_HOME` (jenkins home should be relevant) , if will be different, then reconfigure at Jenkins UI